# How to reformat a given array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting variable data of multiple database tables from a html form post. The Post array need to be formated to be used as array to update the data in the table where it's coming from.

The array from the POST:

```
Array
(
    [test_id] => 1
    [appl_id] => 1
    [Test_code] => 0
    [test_date] => 2017-03-09
    [test_type] => 46
)
```

The best result of what I need was running it through a foreach loop and formating Key and Value as needed:

```
$data = "";
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    $data .= "'".$key."' => '".$value."',<br />";
}

TblAdmin::update($table, array($data), $param, $id);
```

but it still comes up with:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>'test_id' => '1',
    'appl_id' => '1',
    'Test_code' => '0',
    ....
)
```

and I would need to reformat the array to look like:

```
Array
(
    'test_id' => '1',
    'appl_id' => '1',
    'Test_code' => '0',
    'test_date' => '2017-03-09',
    'test_type' => '46',
)
```

Comment: In your code you are building a string with the content in and it just happens to display it as though it was an array.  BUT why do you just want to copy `$_POST` to `$data`?

Comment: The method I have to update the table data requires that format Which works fin all over. For easy table maintenance I wrote a routine which pulls data from a "x" table in to a dynamic form where the data can be updated and sent back to the database. To store the data back in the Database I need to take apart the post array and put into a query to update the database.

Comment: Agreed with Nigel Ren that this seems quite a bit sketchy. Anyway, your code should never produce that "[0]" thing, according to what you mentioned: https://3v4l.org/j1DWt

Comment: You are right, the variable $data doesn't produce the [0]. That is produced when converting the string back into an array here: "TblAdmin::update($table, array($data), $param, $id);

Comment: This happens because you should not convert string into array. Why not sending `TblAdmin::update` the `$_POST` if you want to add all the data?

Comment: Because there I am having the same problem, getting the post results into a valid PDO statement. The last given array format would match what is needed in the PDO statement to update the database table.

Answer (score 0):

You where all right, the Post array works as is. The problem was coming from the fact that some fields in the database are still empty and trying to update fields in MariaDB with a PDO statement having keys without values does not work. Soon as I set empty values to null or 0 everything works fine.
Summary, I was looking for the mistake at the wrong place.